# jQuery clone with a simple line break

Tags: jquery, clone

```
<select id="things">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

$('#things').after($('#things').clone());
```

How could I insert a break between these two elements while cloning? Is there a neat way to do it in one line of code? I have tried:

```
$('#things').after('<br/>' + $('#things').clone()); //returns [object object]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ydAdS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add a string, and an object. Create a jQuery object for the `<br/>` instead:

```
$("#things").after( $("<br>").add( $("#things").clone() ) );​​​​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/As2Se/

Comment: although all of these answers work, you seem to be answering all of my questions lately. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#things').after($('#things').clone()).after('<br>');​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#things").clone().insertAfter($("#things")).before('<br>');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/As2Se/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
$('#things').after($('#things').clone().before('<br>'));​​​​​
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Fw46g/